# Calculations with pandas categories

Tags: python, pandas

Is it still possible to do calculations with categorical dtypes?

If not, how can I reduce RAM usage of having categorical ints (very big table of 10m+ entries, with only ~500 unique ints). All calculations must be done as 1 array.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,2,1,3,4,5,6,7],
                   'b':[1,2,3,2,1,3,4,5,6,7]})
df['a'] = df['a'].astype('category')
df['a'] * df['b']
```

In pandas `0.20.3`:

```
Out[23]: 
0     1
1     4
2     9
3     4
4     1
5     9
6    16
7    25
8    36
9    49
dtype: int64
```

This no longer works in newer pandas versions (e.g. `v0.23.0`)

```
TypeError: Series cannot perform the operation *
```

I now need to refactor my code for the newer pandas version, but is there a way to maintain the reduced RAM consumption categories provided?

Comment: How do you plan to store / output the result of your calculation? Do you need the entire result in memory?

Comment: Does that actually decrease RAM/memory usage? I thought categorical replaces the data with an int which is looked up in a hashtable. Or are the int type of the data and the categorical index of seperate precision/bytes?

Comment: I have many steps that  constantly convert int -> category, so all done in RAM. But the final output is a csv file (which is quite small).

Comment: It reduced the RAM usage when I had this equation to calculate:

`df['regression_value'] = (df['k1'] * df['var1'] ) + ... + (df['k9'] + df['var9']) / (something)`

where each column had 10m rows.

Comment: @AH - I try `cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=df['a'].unique())
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(cat_type)` and it failed, so I think the best is ask to [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)

Comment: @jezrael, will do, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround for now, you can use one of [numpy's basic integer types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html):

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,2,1,3,4,5,6,7],
                   'b':[1,2,3,2,1,3,4,5,6,7]})
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(np.int8)
df['b'] = df['b'].astype(np.int8)
>>> df['a'] * df['b']
0     1
1     4
2     9
3     4
4     1
5     9
6    16
7    25
8    36
9    49
dtype: int8
```

Note that this moves the onus on you to be careful for overflows.

Comment: That is useful for the ints, guess I can do the same for the floats, thanks.